# Scroll to div when input has been completed

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a form with three steps and want to 
achieve an effect that when the user completes each step, the next step scrolls up into view. 
How can I achieve this? I am using VUEJS 2.5.2. I have removed some HTML to keep it cleaner and clearer.
Can anyone help with a solution?
My code so far is:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <div id="step1"  v-show="quote.location === 'home'">
          <select v-model="brand">
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select brand</option>
            <option v-for="(car, index) in cars">{{ index }}</option>
          </select>
          <select v-model="model">
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select model</option>
            <option v-for="option in cars[brand]" :value="option.prize">{{ option.prize }}</option>
          </select>
        </div><!--/step1-->
        <div id="step2" v-show="brand && model != ''">
          <h2><span class="text">Do you need an installer?</span></h2>
          <div class="location">
            <div class="selection">
              <input type="radio" id="yesInstaller" name="yesInstaller" value="Yes" v-model="quote.installer">
              <label for="yesInstaller">Yes</label>
            </div>
            <div class="selection">
              <input type="radio" id="noInstaller" name="noInstaller" value="No" v-model="quote.installer">
              <label for="noInstaller">No</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!--/step2-->
        <div id="step3" v-show="quote.installer != ''">
          <h2><span class="text">Right on! Here’s an overview of your selection.</span></h2>
        </div><!--/step2-->
      </form>

  </template>
  <script>
  export default {
    name: 'Quote',
    data () {
      return {
        totalSteps: 4,
        currentStep: 1,
        show: true,
        brand: '',
        model: '',
        cars: {
          'BMW': [ { size:'1', prize:'BMW i3' }, { size:'2',prize:'BMW i8' }, { size:'3',prize:'BMW 740e' } ],
          'AUDI': [ { size:'1', prize:'Audi A3 E-Tron' },{ size:'2', prize:'Audi Q7 E-Tron' } ],
          'Chevrolet': [ { size: '1', prize:'Chevrolet Bolt'}, {size:'1', prize:'Chevrolet Volt' } ],
          'Fiat': [ { size: '1', prize:'Fiat 500e'}]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: You should probably put your v-models in an array and then do something like window.scrollTo to the position of the next question as determined by the index and some identifier in the html for the question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Any chance of example code? I am new to using Vue...

Comment: My suggestion would be to use an existing library: https://github.com/rigor789/vue-scrollTo?ref=madewithvuejs.com

Comment: ok, thank you I will have a look.